# Load a local module in Julia

Tags: julia

I've written a module in Julia using `PkgTemplates` package. The module is saved in `C:/Users/me/.julia/dev/MyModule` folder.

I cannot load the module in other sessions.
I've tried `push!(LOAD_PATH, path)` but didn't work.

Only `include("C:/Users/me/dev/MyModule/src/MyModule.jl")` works but in this case I can only use the functions in the module using `MyModule.myfunction()`.

I couldn't find any other way to load the module.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `Pkg.develop` (or `pkg> develop` in the Pkg REPL mode), see https://julialang.github.io/Pkg.jl/v1/managing-packages/#Adding-a-local-package-1. `Pkg.develop` is basically `Pkg.add` but you install from a local path, for example

```
julia> using Pkg

julia> Pkg.develop(PackageSpec(path = "C:/Users/me/dev/MyModule"))
```

or in the REPL mode:

```
pkg> develop C:/Users/me/dev/MyModule
```

Comment: I'm getting the error `package PackageName [8985d94e] has the same name or UUID as the active project`.

Comment: You are probably trying to add the package to itself then, which doesn't work.